# Magento 2 "There has been an error processing your request"

Tags: magento2

Have just managed to do a clean install of Magento 2 on a local VM, however I am getting lots of "There has been an error processing your request" errors at various points. For example, when trying to Flush the magento cache, or trying to create a new user on the front end. I have made no changes to anything since installation - I am simply trying to get a working fresh installation so that I can have a look around.

When Navigating to **/customer/account/create/**, seeing the above error and checking the error logs, I receive the following:

> "Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:5235:"#0
>   /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponent/Config/Reader.php(95)"

At a bit of a loss as to why I am getting these errors, as this is a fresh install. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you please tell me magento version which your are used ?

Comment: @SHPatel I am using Magento 2.0.4 Community

Comment: Have you checked your php error logs?

Comment: @JackieLowery Yep, and no errors appear in there when I recreate the errors on the front end of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by deleting (renaming) the **/generation** directory under **/var** in the Magento install.